# .NET library for working with mobile devices eg PDA

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

Does anyone know any good .net libraries for working with PDAs and such?

I mainly looking for something that will allow me to copy files to/from devices and do some registry work on the device.  The PDAs are running windows mobile 5 & 6

I have been using the OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPI library in a couple of my apps but I was just interested to see what other people are using.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

.NET CF 2.0 has a built-in Registry namespace for dealing with the registry.

The CF applications that I write usually talk to a web service running under IIS on a server.  If the application needs a file from the server, the web service returns it as a byte array.  RAPI can be a royal pain, and I've managed to avoid it successfully so far.